# ValueError: 'c' argument has 224 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 32

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a `draw_umap` utility function to fit the data with UMAP given a set of parameter choices, and plot the result.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import umap

le = LabelEncoder()
clinical = clinical.apply(le.fit_transform)
clinical_data = clinical[["pstage", "age", "race", "gender", "ethnicity", "survival", "subtype", ]].values

def draw_umap(n_neighbors=15, min_dist=0.1, n_components=2, metric='euclidean', title=''):
    fit = umap.UMAP(
        n_neighbors=n_neighbors,
        min_dist=min_dist,
        n_components=n_components,
        metric=metric
    )
    u = fit.fit_transform(clinical_data);
    fig = plt.figure()
    if n_components == 1:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.scatter(u[:,0], range(len(u)), c=data)
    if n_components == 2:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.scatter(u[:,0], u[:,1], c=clinical_data)
    if n_components == 3:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(100, projection='3d')
        ax.scatter(u[:,0], u[:,1], u[:,2], c=clinical_data, s=111)
    plt.title(title, fontsize=18)

for n in (2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200):
    draw_umap(n_neighbors=n, title='n_neighbors = {}'.format(n))
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:4439, in Axes._parse_scatter_color_args(c, edgecolors, kwargs, xsize, get_next_color_func)
   4438 try:  # Is 'c' acceptable as PathCollection facecolors?
-> 4439     colors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c)
   4440 except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:487, in to_rgba_array(c, alpha)
    486 else:
--> 487     rgba = np.array([to_rgba(cc) for cc in c])
    489 if alpha is not None:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:487, in <listcomp>(.0)
    486 else:
--> 487     rgba = np.array([to_rgba(cc) for cc in c])
    489 if alpha is not None:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:299, in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    298 if rgba is None:  # Suppress exception chaining of cache lookup failure.
--> 299     rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    300     try:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:383, in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    382 if len(c) not in [3, 4]:
--> 383     raise ValueError("RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4")
    384 if not all(isinstance(x, Number) for x in c):
    385     # Checks that don't work: `map(float, ...)`, `np.array(..., float)` and
    386     # `np.array(...).astype(float)` would all convert "0.5" to 0.5.

ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for n in (2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200):
----> 2     draw_umap(n_neighbors=n, title='n_neighbors = {}'.format(n))

Input In [21], in draw_umap(n_neighbors, min_dist, n_components, metric, title)
     13 if n_components == 2:
     14     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
---> 15     ax.scatter(u[:,0], u[:,1], c=clinical_data)
     16 if n_components == 3:
     17     ax = fig.add_subplot(100, projection='3d')

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1442, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1439 @functools.wraps(func)
   1440 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441     if data is None:
-> 1442         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1444     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1446                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:4602, in Axes.scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4599 if edgecolors is None:
   4600     orig_edgecolor = kwargs.get('edgecolor', None)
   4601 c, colors, edgecolors = \
-> 4602     self._parse_scatter_color_args(
   4603         c, edgecolors, kwargs, x.size,
   4604         get_next_color_func=self._get_patches_for_fill.get_next_color)
   4606 if plotnonfinite and colors is None:
   4607     c = np.ma.masked_invalid(c)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:4445, in Axes._parse_scatter_color_args(c, edgecolors, kwargs, xsize, get_next_color_func)
   4443 else:
   4444     if not valid_shape:
-> 4445         raise invalid_shape_exception(c.size, xsize) from err
   4446     # Both the mapping *and* the RGBA conversion failed: pretty
   4447     # severe failure => one may appreciate a verbose feedback.
   4448     raise ValueError(
   4449         f"'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, "
   4450         f"or a sequence of numbers, not {c!r}") from err

ValueError: 'c' argument has 224 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 32.
```

Data:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'pstage': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 0},
 'age': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 7,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 17,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 12,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 20,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 10,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 4,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 14,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 4,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 11},
 'malignancy_type': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 1},
 'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 0},
 'days_to_last_follow_up': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 16,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 26,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 14,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 8,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 12,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 7,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 23},
 'race': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 0},
 'gender': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 1,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 1},
 'ethnicity': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 0},
 'vital_status': {'TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.Y8.A895.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.MH.A855.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7842.01A': 0,
  'TCGA.DW.7841.01A': 0}})
```